# Refactoring a Delimiter

Tags: ruby

Is there a more cleaner approach to this? I'm doing the String calculator Kata posted by Roy Osherove. I realized that my calculator has no way of clearing out a previous expression after calling add. How can I handle this, and also how can I cut down the number of methods?

Here's a valid string: `calc.add("//+\n1+2")`

Here's an invalid string: `calc.add("//b\n1b2")`

```
class StringCalculator
  attr_reader :numbers

  def initialize(numbers = '')
    @numbers = numbers
  end

  def add(expression)
    @numbers << expression
    return nil if @numbers.end_with("\n")
    @numbers.gsub!(/\n/, delimiter)
    @numbers.empty? ? 0 : solution
  end

  private

  def valid_delimiters
    [*(33..46), *(58..64)].map(&:chr).join
  end

  def solution
    numerics = @numbers.split(delimiter).map(&:to_i)
    find_negatives(numerics)
    numerics.reduce(:+)
  end

  def find_negatives(numerics)
    negatives = numerics.select { |n| n < 0 }
    fail "negatives not allowed: #{negatives.join(', ')}" if negatives.any?
  end

  def supports?
    valid_delimiters.include?(@numbers[2, 1])
  end

  def delimiter
    return ',' unless @numbers.match(%r{^//})
    supports? ? @numbers[2, 1] : fail('Unsupported delimiter')
  end
end
```

Comment: so, delimiter is set only on the first `add` (or in the constructor)?

Comment: It's set in add, the constructor only creates the string I want to evaluate. @UriAgassi

Comment: But it is set only on the _first_ time you call `add`, right?

Comment: Could you add the requirements for the class (what happens when a string ends in `\n`, etc...)

Comment: I have tests for this, but here's the specs for the code: http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/ @UriAgassi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the code seems to be missing - I can't see where you assign `@numbers`. I'm going to assume that it is set to `"//+\n1+2"` or the like.

**DRY** - twice in your code you calculate the delimiter (`@numbers[2,1]`), either pass it as an argument, or make it a method.

Btw, you seem to have a syntax error there, you might have meant to say `supports? ? @numbers...` instead.

**Be clear, not clever** you show good control in ranges, array, chars, etc., but still the following will be much clearer to future readers of your code (you included!)

```
ValidDelimiters = "!\"\\#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@"
```

(if you don't like to see escaped sequences, you can use `%{!"\#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@}` instead)

**Be Ruby** - when you need to return a boolean, which is returned on a condition, there is no need to explicitly say `.. ? true : false`, simply return the condition result

**Harness the power of regular expressions** - when matching strings, captures are set to [`$n`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441152/ruby-what-does-1-mean) variables - you can use this to check your delimiter more elegantly:

```
ValidDelimiters = "!\"\\#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@"

def supports?(delim)
   ValidDelimiters.include? delim
end

def delimiter
  return ',' unless @numbers.match(%r{^//(.)})
  delim = $1
  supports?(delim) ? delim  : fail('Unsupported delimiter')
end
```

**Edit** - with the new code

**Naming** - choose names that convey the meaning of the member - `@numbers` implicitly say it is a group of numbers, although it is actually a string... better name might be `input_expression` or something like that.

**Redundant code with side-effects** - your constructor accepts a string as input, which you assign to `@numbers`. This is not part of the requirements, and you probably don't have tests for that, but it may have serious impact on your result!

Also, for each time you call `add`, the input is concatenated to the end of the previous result (also not part of the requirements), which *will* break your code.

**Assume nothing** - Ruby's `to_i` method is very liberal - anything that is not a number will be parsed to - `0`, so an input like `"1,2,goat,3"` will give a valid result of 6...

**When state is redundant** - when assuming each add is supposed to be a separate calculation - no state is needed. You can simply pass the expression around to your helper methods, and return the result. You can even turn your class into a [`module`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html), with all methods being class methods, and the usage will be `StringCalculator.add('//+\n1+2')

Comment: I'll update this with how I append numbers. Sorry about that. Give me just a second, don't go anywhere!

Comment: I thought about making this procedural after realizing that when my tests broke after calling add twice. So I'm assuming a module would just include methods without being object-oriented (which is what you're saying about the object state.) What exactly are you saying about ```to_i```. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: What would your code return if I called `calc.add('1,2,goat,3')`? Is this what you expect it to return?

Comment: It returned six. So it did in fact parse goat into zero. By converting this into a module, this would be all procedural, correct?

Comment: It won't be object-oriented, but for simple code like this, you doesn't have to be. If a requirement will come, which will require state - you could refactor it then, according to the new requirement.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the insight. This problem was trivial at first and then I lost control flow as I started moving down on the specs.

Comment: One last question, how do I test this with rspec? Do I just include the module when describing StringCalculator? I can't find an example that just tests a module.

Comment: Since all your methods should be class methods (`def self.add(expression)`, you don't need to include the module, simply call the method is your test (`expect(StringCalculator.add(...)).to ...`)